# MacBook Pro late 2011 graphics card dead?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a bit of an issue with my MacBook Pro late 2011 13". While I was working it slowed down, so I decided to shut down all applications and restart the computer. In the booting process of rebooting the screen started to flicker and eventually it turned black. I restarted again and after the starting peep tone the screen turned to black and white stripes. I googled for that issue and soon had to find out that probably the graphics card is overheated/dead.

However, I just started the computer again and everything worked well and I was even able to login again. After a couple of seconds it started to flicker again and then the stripes appeared again.

Now I'm not sure whether the graphics card is dead or not, as everything worked perfectly fine for a moment after the issue appeared for the first time.

Any ideas what I could do or what causes the issue? ...I'm currently working remotely from Indonesia so I can't really get any help from an apple store.

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's a known problem with the video card on late 2011 MacBook Pros. I had a similar problem a year or two ago, and when I brought it in to the Genius Bar they replaced the motherboard for free, even though these devices are long out of warranty.

Comment: Yeah, apparently there was an exchange program on late 2011 MacBook Pros, but it ended in December 2016, so probably they won't change it anymore for free. But I'm still wondering, why everything worked fine for a couple of minutes and then stopped again. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: When it happened to me, the machine rebooted OK the first time, then the next day it flaked out again, this time it stayed dead. So it's kind of random when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Mac and the same issue. It's a known issue as explained by @Barmar. There are many post like this one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/836910/disable-discrete-graphics-card-on-macbook-pro-early-2011) which explain how to disable the graphic card to use the integrated one. I did it recently. This will allow you to use your Mac in a degraded mode. Depending on how you use your Mac, it might be good enough.